# How to run multiple T(Threaded)Server?

Tags: java, thrift

I want to run two `TThreadedPoolServers` in the same program to handle different kinds of requests. However, the `TThreadedPoolServer` that starts last will always refuse the connection if a client tries to connect to it. I've already tried to run the servers in different threads, but to no avail.

Server 1:

```
public class RERunner extends Thread {
    private static ReceiveEndpoint receiveEndpoint;
    private static ReceiveEndpointInterface.Processor<ReceiveEndpoint> masterProcessor;

    public RERunner() throws TTransportException {
        receiveEndpoint = new ReceiveEndpoint();
        masterProcessor = new ReceiveEndpointInterface.Processor<>(receiveEndpoint);

        TServerTransport transport = new TServerSocket(Elements.MASTER_SERVER_RC_ENDPOINT_PORT);
        TSimpleServer server = new TSimpleServer(new TSimpleServer.Args(transport).processor(masterProcessor));
        server.serve();
    }
}
```

Server 2:

```
public class RETableRunner extends Thread {
    private static ReceiveEndpointTable receiveEndpointTable;
    private static ReceiveEndpointTableInterface.Processor<ReceiveEndpointTable> masterProcessorTable;

    public RETableRunner() throws TTransportException {
        receiveEndpointTable = new ReceiveEndpointTable();
        masterProcessorTable = new ReceiveEndpointTableInterface.Processor<>(receiveEndpointTable);

        TServerTransport transportAll = new TServerSocket(Elements.MASTER_SERVER_RC_ENDPOINT_TABLE_PORT);
        TThreadPoolServer serverAll = new TThreadPoolServer(new TThreadPoolServer.Args(transportAll).processor(masterProcessorTable));
        serverAll.serve();
    }
}
```

And the Exception thrown clientside:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226)
    at DataPropagator.acquireEndpointTable(DataPropagator.java:27)
    at DataPropagator.run(DataPropagator.java:98)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)  
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221)
    ... 2 more
```

The solution doesn't have to contain two `TThreadedPoolServers`, but if it doesn't, I'll need help starting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, the TThreadedPoolServer that starts last will always refuse the connection if a client tries to connect to it. I've already tried to run the servers in different threads, but to no avail.

That's not so much an issue of the (threaded) server, but a general problem you will run into when trying to bind two servers to one socket.

One possible solution when you need to run two or more servers over the same endpoint is to use the [multiplex protocol](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-563).

Some (not all) implementations also provide a compatibility fallback to a default service, if an older client (one not using `TMultiplexProtocol`) is contacting the server. If the implementation does not currently support it, be aware that adding `TMultiplexProtocol` to an existing and published endpoint is a breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

I combined the two *.thrift files and the services defined in them, so that I could access both functions through just one TThreadedServer.

Comment: The [multiplex protocol](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-563) comes in handy when running multiple services over one endpoint. BTW your accepted answer may solve your particular problem, but does not really *answer* the question, does it?